$wpdb->update is not working until next page refresh. Is there one more step?
When I update a post and then re-get that post to check if it worked, it does not seem to have worked, but it actually did. Is there a purge_db_cache() kind of thing?
$pid  = 55276;
$post = get_post($pid);

echo 'original post:<BR>'.$post->post_excerpt.'<HR>';
// 'some textt1'


$newtext = 'some textt2';
global $wpdb;
$worked = $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, ['post_excerpt' => $newtext], ['ID' => $pid]);
echo 'update worked?: '.$worked.'<HR>';// 1  //int|false The number of rows updated, or false on error.

$post = get_post($pid);
echo 'new post:<BR>'.$post->post_excerpt.'<BR>';
// 'some textt1'


When you use $wpdb->update in WordPress, it updates the database immediately, but WordPress might still show cached data. To ensure the updated data is displayed right away, you should manually clear the post cache using clean_post_cache($pid); after the update. Here's the adjusted code:
$pid  = 55276;
$post = get_post($pid);

echo 'original post:<BR>'.$post->post_excerpt.'<HR>';

$newtext = 'some textt2';
global $wpdb;
$worked = $wpdb->update($wpdb->posts, ['post_excerpt' => $newtext], ['ID' => $pid]);
echo 'update worked?: '.$worked.'<HR>';

// Clear the post cache
clean_post_cache($pid);

// Fetch the post again
$post = get_post($pid);
echo 'new post:<BR>'.$post->post_excerpt.'<BR>';

